# Is recommending a paid-for knowledge library acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Is it frowned upon to recommend an external knowledge library you pay a subscription to in the comments? I shall explain.

If a user asks a question, be it broad or not, is it acceptable to recommend a resource in the comments that you think might be beneficial to the user, for example a Pluralsight module?

I have seen posts on recommending books or external sites, and I get the impression it is generally acceptable to do so in a comment. However, if the resource you think might be beneficial is a resource you pay a subscription to (for example, Pluralsight) should you generally avoid recommending modules from that site?

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [When is it appropriate to link to your own paywalled website from your answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140393/165773)

Comment: Feel free to recommend anything, as long as you're not an employee of pluralsight I wouldn't consider it to be spam. That said, those type of questions should be flagged as they are off topic. _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: @George Only if the request for recommendations is in the question anyway. No one has been flagging answers for recommending jQuery. ;)

Comment: @E_net4 You mean to tell me you can write JavaScript **without** using jQuery?

Comment: @George once you are good enough, you **become** jQuery.

Comment: Whether the thing you recommend is free or not doesn't matter. I think you should avoid doing this for questions that do ask for recommendations, even in the comments, since that encourages them to keep asking off-topic questions. Other than that though, I don't see any reason you shouldn't be able to recommend a tool/resource that costs money.